# Advantage of function taking a pointer to a collection, to avoid copying on return?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Suppose I have the following C++ function:

```
// Returns a set containing {1!, 2!, ..., n!}.
set<int> GetFactorials(int n) {
  set<int> ret;
  int curr = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    curr *= i;
    ret.insert(curr);
  }

  return ret;
}

set<int> fs = GetFactorials(5);
```

(This is just a dummy example. The key is that the function creates the set itself and returns it.)

One of my friends tells me that instead of writing the function the way I did, I should write it so that the function takes in a pointer to a set, in order to avoid copying the set on return. I'm guessing he meant something like:

```
void GetFactorials2(int n, set<int>* fs) {
  int curr = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    curr *= i;
    fs->insert(curr);
  }
}

set<int> fs;
GetFactorials2(5, &fs);
```

My question: is this second way really a big advantage? It seems pretty weird to me. I'm new to C++, and don't know much about compilers, but I would assume that through some compiler magic, my original function wouldn't be that much more expensive. (And I'd get to avoid having to initialize the set myself.) Am I wrong? What should I know about pointers and copying-on-return to understand this?

Comment: Google for RVO and NRVO.

Comment: For the record, unless the Collection or List class has a deep copy implemented, the difference between pointer or reference and value passing will be much less significant and it will be fixed in magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is generally not advantageous at all. Just about any reasonable compiler these days will utilize named return value optimization (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)). This effectively removes any performance penalty from the former example.

If you really want to get into the nitty gritty, read [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) by Dave Abrahams (one of the big contributors to boost). Long story short, however, just return the value. It's probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be expensive. Especially when the set gets bigger. There is no reason not to use pointers or reference here. It will save you a lot and you don't sacrifice much regarding readability.

And why rely on compiler optimizations when you can optimize it yourself. The compiler knows your code but not always understands your algorithm.

I would do this

```
void GetFactorials2(int n, set<int>& fs) {
//                                   ^^
  int curr = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    curr *= i;
    fs->insert(curr);
  }
}
```

and the call will stay normal.

```
set<int> fs;
GetFactorials2(5, fs);
                  ^^
```

Comment: Uglier code, loss of referential transparency, extra code required at call site, for no benefit in 99% of situations.

Comment: @Yuushi The extra call at call site? you mean the extra `fs`? You are willing to depend on compiler optimization not to write that?

Comment: You've introduced a potential bug if the set is not empty when calling the function :P. It's just a matter of taste I guess, but I feel it's less readable and (potentially) requires more checks and perhaps, in the end, might even be a few nanoseconds slower than if you just _wrote code to do what you meant_ instead of trying to workaround problems that don't exist.

Comment: @Yuushi and to be complete ROV is a relatively new optimization. It is not even available on all compilers. I would rather right a proper code than to just let it go and hope the compiler optimizes it.

Comment: A relatively new optimization which was implemented by Walter Bright in *1991*. This falls squarely into the camp of premature optimization  and is thus 97% likely to be evil, as the saying goes...